# C++/SDL Memory Management

Tags: c++, memory, sdl

I'm working on a simple scrolling space shooter. I have a Sprite class inherited by Entity Class objects. I'm getting memory leak from these objects. I tested this with the main menu for this game and I believe the issue lies within the sprite class.

The issue with the memory seems to be that I am not SDL_Destroy..ing the texture and renderer. However, by destroying the texture, I get wild results with one texture being substituted for another, or no texture at all. If I destroy the renderer, no images will load. If I destroy neither then everything loads fine, but there's memory leak.

I believe the wild textures have to do with the way I'm handling vectors of objects, but I don't know of another way to handle them..

the Sprite class:

```
Sprite::Sprite()
{
}

Sprite::Sprite(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer, std::string filePath, int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
_renderer = pRenderer;
_filePath = filePath;

_image = IMG_LoadTexture(_renderer, filePath.c_str());

_rect.x = x;
_rect.y = y;
_rect.w = w;
_rect.h = h;
}

Sprite::~Sprite()
{
std::cout<<_filePath<<" destroyed"<<std::endl;
SDL_DestroyTexture(_image);
//SDL_DestroyRenderer(_renderer);

}
void Sprite::draw()
{
SDL_RenderCopy(_renderer, _image, NULL, &_rect);
}
```

I have several vectors that produce bullets, asteroids, etc.. That all use the Sprite class. I use code similar to this to handle their deletion when they are no longer needed:

```
if (!update)
{
     vector[i] = vector.back;
     vector.pop_back;
}
```

The Asteroid class is just one of the classes that is changing images randomly.. It inherits Entity, which inherits Sprite.. not sure if it's also leaking memory. It's hard to test with everything else..

here is the asteroid class:

```
Asteroid::Asteroid(SDL_Renderer* pRenderer) :

_health(50)
{
_renderer = pRenderer;

_posX = getRandom(800);
_posY = -50;
_width = 30;
_height = 30;

_velocityX = getRandom(2);
_velocityY = getRandom(2);

initSprite(pRenderer, "Asteroid.png", _posX, _posY, _width, _height);

 }

Asteroid::~Asteroid()
{

//EMPTY
}

bool Asteroid::update(std::vector<Bullet>& bullets,
                  std::vector<Block>& blocks)
{
//COLLISION BULLET
for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
{
    if (collisionCheck(bullets[i].getRect()))
    {
        //CHANGE VELOCITY & POSITION
        _velocityY -= 0.2f;

        _posY -= 3;

        //TAKE DAMAGE
        _health -= 10;
    }
}

if(_posY >= 500)
{
    return false;
}

//IF DEAD
if (_health <= 0)
{
    return false;
}

//MOVEMENT
drift();

return true;
}

void Asteroid::draw()
{
Entity::draw();
}

void Asteroid::drift()
{
//move position
_posX += _velocityX;
_posY += _velocityY;

//check boundaries
if (_posY > 0) {
    if (_posX < 0)
    {
        _velocityX *= -1;
    }
    if (_posX > 800 - _width)
    {
        _velocityX *= -1;
    }
    if (_posY < 0)
    {
     _velocityY *= -1;
    }
    if (_posY > 600 - _height)
    {
        _velocityY *= -1;
    }
}

}

bool Asteroid::collisionCheck(SDL_Rect rect2)
{
return !(_rect.x > rect2.x + rect2.w || _rect.x + _rect.w < rect2.x ||
         _rect.y > rect2.y + rect2.h || _rect.y + _rect.h < rect2.y );
}

int Asteroid::getRandom(int threshold)
{
 _randomNumber = rand() % threshold + 1;

return _randomNumber;}
```

I'm new to C++, but learning quick. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your vectors are storing the objects directly.  Thus as the objects are copied/moved around they will be destroying textures when they shouldn't be.

For instance, I assume that you haven't implemented a custom copy constructor...  so say you have a `std::vector<Sprite>` and you're trying to add a new object to it like this:

```
{
  Sprite s(renderer, "image.png", 0, 0, 100, 100);
  sprites.push_back(s);
}
```

When you do that, `s` will load the texture.  When you push it onto the `sprites` vector it will create a copy of `s` (so now they both have the same `_image` value).  Then on the next line (when `s` goes out of scope), `s` will destroy the texture -- yet the copy in the `sprites` vector is still trying to reference it!

Instead of having vectors of the objects themselves, try having a vector of `std::shared_ptr`s to them.  Like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Sprite> > sprites;
std::shared_ptr<Sprite> s(new Sprite(renderer, "image.png", 0, 0, 100, 100));
sprites.push_back(s);
```

This way only pointers are being copied, and there will only be one real object (and it will be automatically deleted when no one is referencing it).

Take a look at the [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) docs for more information.

Comment: new to stack overflow.. sorry for duplicate post.. this is what i was trying to say:



I will definitely look into shared pointer, but I am adding objects to the vector with emplace_back and giving each object it's own values. idk if that makes a difference..

I've actually "solved" the problem with a texture manager class, but I'm still not 100% sure.. When you say there's only one real object and everything else references it, is this similar to a texture/resource manager?

How can you reference one object, but have it occupy multiple positions at once?

Comment: Even if you're adding the object with emplace_back, as the vector grows/shrinks it will make copies of the contained objects.

Comment: How do I reference the object? For example collision with a projectile. As it is now I pass the vector into the function, but so far I'm unable to do this with shared_ptr